# Can't receive correct data from bluetooth module in arduino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I wanted to check if my bluetooth module for arduino works so I've looked for simple tutorials how to connect and program arduino in order to use bluetooth with it.

I've used this schematic to connect my arduino and BT.
http://cdn.instructables.com/F4V/PPKD/HITAAYZC/F4VPPKDHITAAYZC.LARGE.jpg

I successfully managed to pair my BT module with both phone and tablet (one at the time ofc), also I had no problems with sending data throu my BT module to this devices (phone/tablet).
Unfortunalty I can't receive any correct data from my devices.

I've tried 2 ways:

SoftwareSerial connection - which gives me literaly nothing when I check `BTSerial.available()>0`(sending data to any of mentioned devices works correct).

Hardware serial connection - with no success on Serial1/Serial2/Serial3 BUT here at least when I check Serial1 (for example) for incoming bytes I get info about 1 byte incoming.
 Unfortunatly it is some sort of wrong kind of data because if I send char "a" from my phone via SENA BTterm I get 0 (as int) and some weird character (if I store this data in char variable).

I assume that my BT module works fine beause if it wouldn't I couldn't establish connection with any other devices.

Some code that I use:

Software Serial:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); // RX | TX
// Connect the HC-05 TX to Arduino pin 2 RX. 
// Connect the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 3 TX through a voltage divider.
// 

char c = ' ';

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino is ready");

    // HC-05 default serial speed for commincation mode is 9600
    BTserial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop()
{
    // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
    //Serial.write("yolo");
    if (BTserial.available() > 0)
    {  
        Serial.write("yolo");
        c = BTserial.read();
        Serial.write(c);
    }

    // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        //Serial.write("yolo");
        c =  Serial.read();
        BTserial.println(c);  
    }
}
```

Hardware serial version:

```
char data;
char data2;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial1.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.print("Incoming bytes:");
    Serial.println(Serial1.available());
    data = Serial1.read();
    Serial.println(data);
  }

  data2 = Serial.read();

  if(data2 != -1)
  {
    Serial.print( "Sending: ");
    Serial.println( data2);
    Serial1.println(data2);
  }

  //delay(200);
}
```

Comment: Trust me. Find a **better** tutorial. I never needed a `resistive partitor` to connect an HC-05 or HC-06. And I never needed `more than one built-in` Serial object.

Comment: On the back of my BT modul there is written "3.3V" on RX and TX pin

Comment: Then don't connect it to 5V, but to the 3V3 Arduino pin. OR, use a 3.3V Zener diode, if your custom Arduino board hasn't a 3V3 pin.

Comment: RX and TX on BT modul are connected to serial input and output on arduino which comunicate on 5V so it is pointless to switch the way of reducing voltage if we agree that i got to reduce it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem was to simply change Serial port that will comunicate with BT module to Serial0. Simpliest solutions are the bests.

Answer (score 2):

I post my solution here because I've been having trouble with the same problem but couldn't find the solution anywhere. So I hope this will help many folks out there. If you have an Arduino Mega board and are using the Software Serial library, keep in mind that not all pins on the board will work as RX.

As stated in the library subwebsite:
" Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12 (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69) "

More information here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

Hope this helps as it did with me